# c# object generic use without casting?

Tags: c#, object, casting

```
object s;
s = "abc";
int n = ((string)s).Length;
```

Is there any way of avoiding having to use the cast in the 3rd line?

edit: "string" and "length" are just examples and could be different.

edit: Further clarified regarding var and dynamic by breaking up the first line to be more like my requirements.

Comment: @ala2here I already answered.

Comment: Sorry, edited in "edit: ". I didn't mean to catch you out :¬P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dynamic s = "abc";
int n = s.Length;
```

Comment: Personally, I believe that those who sacrifice type safety for a little liberty, deserve neither liberty nor type safety.

Comment: There are varying points of view on this issue. Some modern languages are actually designed so all vars are like dynamic. Personally I think it's beneficial beyond just expressiveness.

Comment: @alan2here Yes, but C# is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int n = s.ToString().Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could us the .ToString() which is on all objects.